# #EMERGENCY!!! Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'b' was corrupted

Tags: c

I know this seems like an old question, but none answered questions I searched work.
I have kept receiving "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'b' was corrupted." when I was trying to do a [4][2]*[2][3] matrix multiplication.

Does anyone spot the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[4][2] = {0};
    int b[2][3] = {0};
    int c[3][3] = {0};
    int i, j;
    printf("Please enter first matrix value\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d row, %d column:", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Please enter second matrix value\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d row, %d column:", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n the result is :\n");//
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("[");
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            c[i][j] = (a[i][0] * b[0][j]) + (a[i][1] * b[1][j]);
            printf(" %4d ", c[i][j]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ##DONT SHOUT !!!!

Comment: should be `int c[4][3] = {0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't checked your code thoroughly, but you define c as 3x3, and here

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("[");
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        c[i][j] = (a[i][0] * b[0][j]) + (a[i][1] * b[1][j]);
```

...you access c[3], which is c's *fourth* element, and does not exist. This is bound to write *somewhere else*.

So check your indexes (as @ptb observed, c's should actually be four rows deep).